# Repeating a function down a list, without repeating code

Tags: google-docs, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've written a script in google docs to use =importXML function and return the value on its own rather than leaving the function there loading on opening and every hour slowing the thing down.
Basically it uses the data in row D (hidden), sticks the formula in B2, then, overwrites B2 with the value of the formula. I then wanted to repeat this going down the list but just didn't know how - currently I've just repeated the function and changed the cell ID, which I'm aware is a travesty. Could someone guide a noob on how to do it efficiently?

```
function pullValues() 
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var cellref1 = sheet.getRange("D2");
var ID = cellref1.getValue();
var apistring = "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?usesystem=30000142&typeid=" + ID;
var command = "importxml(\"" + apistring + "\", \"/evec_api/marketstat/type/sell/min\")";
var cellref2 = sheet.getRange("B2");
cellref2.setFormula(command);
var val = cellref2.getValue();
cellref2.setValue(val);
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjZlH_sGnj6vdDU4QWdyZTVTd2E4RUFXZnVEZlZJS3c#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through all rows in the spreadsheet using a for loop. There are many ways to do it, the following code is one of them:

```
function pullValues() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();   // Last row of data to process

  for (var i = startRow; i <= lastRow; i++)
  {
    var cellref1 = sheet.getRange("D" + i);
    var ID = cellref1.getValue();
    var apistring = "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?usesystem=30000142&typeid=" + ID;
    var command = "=ImportXML(\"" + apistring + "\", \"/evec_api/marketstat/type/sell/min\")";
    var cellref2 = sheet.getRange("B" + i);
    cellref2.setFormula(command);
    var val = cellref2.getValue();
    cellref2.setValue(val);
  }
}
```